# What happens when I deal lethal damage to everyone at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In an EDH game, I was able to get infinite mana, and I used it to cast a [Squall Line](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=109702) with X = 1,000,000. What is the result of this decision? Do I win, or does everyone lose and thus tie?

Answer (score 8):

The relevant rule is this one:

> [104.4a](http://www.yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#R1044a). If all the players remaining in a game lose simultaneously, the game is a draw.

So the game is a draw. Nobody wins.

Comment: You might however be able to convince your friends that you have achieved a moral victory by ending the game on your own terms!

Comment: Equally all your friends might decide it was the desperate act of someone losing and count it as a loss for you :)